# Select the 2 latest "group/batch" records from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have data like in this mysql table:

```
id  customer_id  int_proc
1   A               1
2   A               4
3   A               5
4   A               5
5   A               5
6   A               5
7   B               6           
8   B               7
9   B               9
10  B               9
10  B               9
11  C               22
```

I want to get all data from the latest 2 int_proc values where the customer_id is A and B.

My result should be like this:

```
id  customer_id  int_proc
2   A               4
3   A               5
4   A               5
5   A               5
6   A               5
8   B               7
9   B               9
10  B               9
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, it's not a 'possible duplicate' - it's a direct one: instead of updating this question with the details the OP missed he opened another one (that was answered).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.ID 
       ,t.Customer_id
       ,t.Int_Proc
FROM TestTable t 
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT Customer_Id , MIN(Int_Proc) as Int_Proc
             FROM TestTable
             GROUP BY Customer_Id )r
ON t.customer_id  = r.customer_id  
AND t.int_proc = r.int_proc
WHERE r.customer_id IS NULL AND r.int_proc IS NULL
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75b0c9/4)

Comment: Thanks. But does it really work? I just added/modified some B parts, it returns more (all) results of B, rather than the latest 2. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90bdc/1